# In WPF, how can I add custom UI component to MainWindow from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF, MVVM light library.

What I want to do is add dynamic generated UI component to Mainwindow. 
From another class like MainViewModel.cs

Usually I make UI components at mainWindow and bind them to public property of MainViewModel.cs. And it worked well.
But When I try to add UI component to MainWindow, it is another problem.
What I did to generate UI component was using custom UI component independant to MainWindow. Like popup. they worked well. But I have no Idea how to add MainWindow.

Is there any good way to do?

Comment: Do not create UI elements in code behind. Use DataTemplates instead. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Dear Clemens. You mean I need to define UIcontrol template I want to add first, use them at MainWIndow as datatemplate, and make data binds to the datatemplate?

Comment: Please read the article first.

Comment: Dear Clemens. As you saying, I'm reading the article. I just wanter to ensure What I'm thinking at first glance is in right way. I understand using template is official and good way to solve but takes time to complete understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Clemens. After reading several documents and guids, frankly, I don't understand the idea of the items template. Maybe it's because I don't have basic knowledge about this WPF/XAML. Maybe I need to find out another way. I don't really understand Why the blocked way to let us make UI component and add them to main window directly. Thank you.

Comment: It's not that you can't create UI elements in code behind, it's just bad practice and not the recommended way. However, understanding the concept of DataTemplates is essential if you want to use the full power of WPF. Try it with a book, e.g. "WPF Unleashed" by Adam Nathan.

Comment: Dear Clemens. Thank you very much for kind advice. I don't know the reason but WPF reference book is not published for almost 10 years in South Korea. I'll check the book.

Comment: The WPF 4.5 version is from 2013: https://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-5-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672336979/ref=asc_df_0672336979/?adgrpid=65855312310&hvadid=310654880846&hvadid=310654880846&hvdev=c&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9043412&hvlocphy=9043412&hvnetw=g&hvnetw=g&hvpone=&hvpone=&hvpos=1o1&hvpos=1o1&hvptwo=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvqmt=&hvrand=14155768625244564358&hvrand=14155768625244564358&hvtargid=pla-449095480220&hvtargid=pla-449095480220&language=en_US&linkCode=df0&psc=1&psc=1&ref=&tag=&tag=googshopde-21&th=1